# Is it possible to have 2 methods (GET and POST) with the same route?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http, asp.net-mvc-routing

I would like to have 2 methods in my controller that have the same route but differ only in the HTTP method. Specifically, if my route looks like

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "DataRoute",
    url: "Sample/{user}/{id}/",
    defaults: new { controller = "Sample", action = "--not sure--", user = "", id = "" }
);
```

and I have 2 methods in my controller as such:

```
[HttpGet]
public void ViewData(string user, string id)

[HttpPost]
public void SetData(string user, string id)
```

The desired behavior is to call `ViewData()` if I GET `Sample/a/b` and call `SetData()` if I POST to `Sample/a/b`, the same URL.

I know I can just create 2 separate routes, but for design reasons I want to have one route differentiated only by `GET` and `POST`. Is there a way to configure either the route or controller to do this without having to create a new route?

Comment: Short answer is no. But you cannot post via a url. Its unclear what your trying to do.

Comment: With attribute routing you should be able to set the same route with different methods.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With attribute routing you should be able to set the same route with different methods.

```
[RoutePrefix("Sample")]
public class SampleController : Controller {
    //eg GET Sample/a/b
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{user}/{id}")]
    public void ViewData(string user, string id) { ... }

    //eg POST Sample/a/b
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("{user}/{id}")]
    public void SetData(string user, string id) { ... }
}
```

Don't forget to enable attribute routing before convention-based routes

```
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```

You should edit the `SetData` method to take some payload from the body of the POST.

```
public void SetData(string user, string id, MyCustomObject data) { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this out. Is there not a way to do this with convention-based routing, though?